# CSS Adding Second Transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, transition

I have a button which when pressed a div would appear from the bottom, and this works with a transition which lasts 0.5 seconds. However, when the div transitions down to disappear it snaps down rather than transitioning smoothly. I have tried but was unable to come up with a way for my div to transition down the same way it transitioned up.

```js
i = 0;

function focusInput() {
  document.getElementById("infoButton").focus();
}
function blurInput() {
  document.getElementById("infoButton").blur();
}

function check() {
  if (i == 0) {
      focusInput()
      i++;
  } else {
      blurInput()
      i--;
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.example::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
.example {
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.settings {
  float: left;
  width: 35%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: right;
}

.settings .infoButton img {
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  width: 15px;
}

.settings .infoButton {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.slide {
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 999;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: #161618;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.5s;
  transition: top 0.5s;
}

.infoButton:focus + .slide {
  visibility: visible;
  top: calc(100vh - 100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="settings">
  <button id="infoButton" onclick="check()" class="infoButton"><img src="https://pics.freeicons.io/uploads/icons/png/7410416951552644391-512.png" alt="settings icon"></button>
  <div class="slide">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my pencode:
https://codepen.io/D4SH13/pen/VwbwgZN

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It’s because you are transitioning only the `top` property, so the change back from `visibility: visible` to `visibility: hidden` happens instantly.

Comment: I have tried but not sure if the formatting was right because it is not working, it is possible to edit my codepen or a reference link? Thank you very much!

Comment: Tried what? All you need to do, is apply a transition for visibility as well - so either make `transition: top 0.5s` into `transition: all 0.5s`, or append a separate transition specification for `visibility` (if you want a different duration, or don’t like `all` because it might affect more than intended.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Visibility` toggles instantly, hence executing before any transitions. The `.slider` is *visible* before the animation, when it's supposed to scroll up, and it's *hidden* before the animation, when it's supposed to scroll down.

Translations over `top` comes with a performance issue. I changed the change in height to `transform: translateY` instead.

You can only animate properties that are numbers, like hexcolors and ... well, ordinary numbers. So I hide the `.slider` by changing it's opacity.

The second parameter in `opacity 1ms 0.5s` is a delay of 0.5 seconds.

I honestly suggest using another solution, because your `.slider` will be at the bottom of the page, and it's still clickable. So I added `pointer-events: none` when `.slider` isn't focused.

I also corrected your javascript code, putting "var" in front of your declaration and changed `i` (now: `sliderOpen`) to a boolean.

```
var sliderOpen = true;

function focusInput() {
  document.getElementById("infoButton").focus();
}
function blurInput() {
  document.getElementById("infoButton").blur();
}
function check() {
  if (sliderOpen) {
      focusInput()
  } else {
      blurInput()
  }

  sliderOpen = !sliderOpen;
}
```

Also, you don't need that javascript code. The CSS is enough to toggle your `.slider`. So I removed it and everything still works.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.example::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
.example {
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.settings {
  float: left;
  width: 35%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: right;
}

.settings .infoButton img {
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  width: 15px;
}

.settings .infoButton {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.slide {
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;  
  background-color: #161618;

  /* CHANGED or ADDED */
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 1ms 0.5s;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.infoButton:focus + .slide {
  /* CHANGED or ADDED */
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 1ms;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="settings">
  <button id="infoButton" class="infoButton"><img src="https://pics.freeicons.io/uploads/icons/png/7410416951552644391-512.png" alt="settings icon"></button>
  <div class="slide">
    <p>Hello</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works like a charm!